# RegionServers consuming too much ram in HDP 2.6

Tags: hbase

When we do any operations on the database(HBase), RegionServers are taking too much ram and not releases until we restart them. Is there any parameter or property to release ram or to restrict RegionServers to take this much of memory? Help will be appreciated.

Comment: how many regions per server do you have?

Comment: Can you please give more information like how much memory region server is taking now, configured heap for regionserver, configured Memstore size, distribution of HBase and how many regions per region server?

Comment: how many regions per region server    :   13-15 , 
 Regins per RS

how much memory region server is taking now  :  16GB,  

Memstore size      :  64 MB,  

configured heap for Master    :  1 GB,  

configured heap for RegionServer   :  1 GB,